# Lyrics of Your Hand On My Shoulder by Jean-François Berger & Cécile Perfetti

Tags: lyrics

Could anyone share the lyrics of Your Hand On My Shoulder by Jean-François Berger & Cécile Perfetti

https://open.spotify.com/album/397yj1XJZdCKnGKsDtV7jL?highlight=spotify:track:6JthCMgR4aoqeYl8HbtVFV

Thank you!

Comment: Seriously no one ... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The silver moon is rising on a quiet, gloomy ocean
I can feel you are smiling to me, tonight I'm in Heaven

You put your arms around me and you whisper " Oh, mon cherie"
Your words are like a music, there is no place where I'd rather be

It is our night forever, all very starry baby
You and me together, no need to worry
As long as you are here with your hand on my shoulder

The silver moon is rising on a quiet, gloomy ocean
I can feel you are smiling to me, tonight I'm in Heaven

You put your arms around me and you whisper " Oh, mon cherie"
Your words are like a music, there is no place where I'd rather be

It is our night forever, all very starry baby
You and me together, no need to worry
As long as you are here with your hand on my shoulder

You put your arms around me and you whisper " Oh, mon cherie"
Your words are like a music, there is no place where I'd rather be

It is our night forever, all very starry baby
You and me together, no need to worry
As long as you are here with your hand on my shoulder
As long as you are here with your hand on my shoulder

Comment: Thank you @LittleVoice so much for the sharing the lyrics. I highly appreciate you sharing it. 

Not sure but "... whisper " Oh, mon cherie" " and " ... very starry baby" lines sounded a bit different to me.

Comment: I'll be happy to update the lyric. How did those particular words sound to you?

Comment: Not sure but it sounds like 

"You put your arms around me and you whispering "cherie [or something]""
"It is all night forever, all fairy story buhie [or something]"